# File format validation

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I write a code in the Asp.net Core project to get the format of the photo file and accept only the jpg format and not any other format?
The code I wrote was this, but it didn't work

```
        pro.ItemId = pro.Id;
     

        if (Product.Picture?.Length > 0)
        {
            string filepath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
                "wwwroot",
                "image",
                pro.Id + Path.GetExtension(Product.Picture.FileName));
            // string Image = @"filepath";
            string Format = Path.GetExtension(filepath);
            if (Format == "jpg")
            {
                using (var stream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    Product.Picture.CopyTo(stream);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Picture", "لطفا تصویر را با فرمت jpg انتخاب کنید.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: It seems reasonable to accept the file, at least initially, based on its extension or mime-type.  Then let the image codec itself handle the case where a file with the wrong extension is supplied.  The jpg format starts with an SOI (start of image) indicator (0xd8) and the codec will verify this and return an error if dealing with bits that aren't valid jpg data.

Comment: I'm downvoting because you posted an image of your code instead of the code itself. 
 Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated). Instead of `string Image = @"filepath";` you probably wanted to do `string Image = $"{filepath}";` but that would just be the same as `string Image = filepath;` and you'd be creating a second variable that would be holding the same value as `filepath`.

Instead, try removing that line and just do `string Format = Path.GetExtension(filepath);`

Comment: Again it didn't work and uploaded the image in png format without showing the error

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve uploaded **Content Type** ([MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type)) in controller and check corresponding format

```
 HttpFileCollection MyFileCollection = Request.Files;

 for (int Loop1 = 0; Loop1 < MyFileCollection.Count; Loop1++)
 {
    if (MyFileCollection[Loop1].ContentType == "image/jpeg")
    {
       //...
    }
 }
```

[Source: Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httppostedfile.contenttype?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually check the byte signatures to verify if it's jpg or any other image file by reading their byte stream, they begin with a unique byte header ex. jpg files begin with "FFD8".

I do actually have a method that covers 4 different image extensions and checks if the image is either jpg/png/bmp/gif;

```
    public static bool ExtensionVerifier(string expectedExtension, IFormFile file)
{
    
    var fileName = file.FileName.Split('.')[0];
        var fileExtension = file.FileName.Split('.')[file.FileName.Split('.').Length-1];
    var pExtension = expectedExtension.ToString().ToLower();
    

    #region Byte_Signatures_of_ImageTypes

    var ImageTypes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    ImageTypes.Add("FFD8", "jpg");
    ImageTypes.Add("424D", "bmp");
    ImageTypes.Add("474946", "gif");
    ImageTypes.Add("89504E470D0A1A0A", "png");

    #endregion


    using (var signatureChecker = file.OpenReadStream())
    {
        signatureChecker.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        int byteHeader = ImageTypes.FirstOrDefault(img => img.Value == fileExtension).Key.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < byteHeader; i += 2)
        {
            string bit = signatureChecker.ReadByte().ToString("X2");
            builder.Append(bit);
            string builtHex = builder.ToString();
            if (ImageTypes.ContainsKey(key: builtHex))
            {
                if (fileExtension == pExtension)
                {
                    signatureChecker.Dispose();
                    return true;
                }

            }

        }
        return false;
    }

}
```